# How to translate model names in rails for error messages in locale yml file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I want to translate the name of the model in the rails auto-generated error messages.

I get the following view error in my rails application when I try to create a new account for a user.

```
AccountSmall is not valid
```

This is correct, because the name for a new account should be present.

How can I now translate the `AccountSmall` name via my yml locale?

I tried this with no luck:

```
de:
  # ...
  activerecord:
    models:
      AccountSmall: "Konto"
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you try using account_small as key for "Konto"? Not sure if this is the right solution, so I post it as comment first.

Comment: I tried this for associated models and it works! I just added the name of the associated model as an attribute to `de.activerecord.attributes.<associated_model>: <human_name>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `AccountSmall` use `account_small` as the key in your locale like so:

```
de:
  activerecord:
    models:
      account_small: "Konto"
```